# classicthesis broader figures/tables to the outer margin

Tags: tables, floats, classicthesis

after five years of writing my phd i am not able to solve the last problem by myself. i´m using classicthesis and i want to set up a command for tables and figures, so that they use a broader margin in direction of the outer margin. to the right for odd pages and to the left for even pages. i found some similar problems, but i wasn´t able to build a solution out of these. maybe i missed a posting about the topic, not searching for the right keywords?

i tried:

- new geometry -> messes with the whole side
- addmargin/addmaring* -> see MWE below
- \areaset -> messes with the whole side

i'm sure it must work with one of these, but i wasn´t able to get it done.

the closest i got to the solution was this MWE. the tables a broader but to the inner margin, not to the outer. Watch out to switch to the bookmode in your pdf-viewer, at least i forgot to do so and it took me a while to understand why a chapter is starting on a left page..

i hope my wme is stripped down sufficiently.

i would appreciate any help very much, almost done this problem drives me crazy!

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,1headlines,
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, 
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,
                ngerman
                ]{scrreprt}
\input{classicthesis-config} 
\usepackage[nochapters,pdfspacing,linedheaders]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\broadtab}[1]{\begin{table}[#1]
        \myfloatalign
\scriptsize 
\begin{addmargin*}[-0.17\textwidth]{} 
        \begin{tabularx}{1.17\textwidth}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\broadtab{h}
{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption1} \label{tab1}
        \end{addmargin*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\broadtab{h}
{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption2} \label{tab2}
        \end{addmargin*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\broadtab{h}
{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption3} \label{tab3}
        \end{addmargin*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\broadtab{h}
{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption4} \label{tab4}
        \end{addmargin*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\broadtab{h}
{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption5} \label{tab5}
        \end{addmargin*}
\end{table}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the pages 2 and 3 of the mwe in bookmode]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are also the fourth possibilities: use of the `changepage` package ... Below is test with packages which are available to me:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,
                numbers=noenddot,headinclude,1headlines,
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,
                ngerman
                ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}% <-- new
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% <-- added that your MWE can be compiled
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-2cm}% extend local border for 2cm in outside direction
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption1} \label{tab1}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-2cm}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption1} \label{tab1}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-2cm}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption1} \label{tab1}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-2cm}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption1} \label{tab1}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-2cm}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\toprule
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
Some long long long long  long long long long Text & Some long long long long  long long long long Text  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Some long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  long long long long  long long long long long long long long  long long long long  caption1} \label{tab1}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked just fine! It took me a while to undertstand that i had the \usepackage{chngpage}, which i didn´t include in my minimal example. After removing it, everything works just fine!

Comment: @hebbbart, `chngpage` is depreciated package name for this package, better is to use `changepage`.

Comment: Ok, so the missing spec [strict] was the problem? I had a lot of problems implementing that solution and i tried dozens of variatons. i am really glad it works now. time to print =)

Comment: Option `strict` make `adjustwidth*` identification, if it is on odd or even page, robust.